# Ignore the word "the" while sorting a Java Collection

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Currently I have some code that takes filenames and sorts them in some different ways (locale-sensitive natural sort, case-insensitive ASCIIbetical sort, by modified date, etc.), for example, for locale-sensitive natural sort it uses this:

```
Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return NaturalComparator.compareNatural(collator, f1.getName(), f2.getName());
    }
});
```

I would like to know how to make it ignore the word "the" at the beginning of a filename, so the instead of ordering files like this:

Apple
Carrot
The Banana

It orders them like this:

Apple
The Banana
Carrot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the first occurrence of `The` before passing it to comparator, using [`String#replaceFirst(regex, replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [`String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods, both of which take a `regex` as parameter to replace, and both can be used here: -

```
@Override
public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
    return NaturalComparator.compareNatural(collator, 
                                          f1.getName().replaceAll("^(?i)The ", ""), 
                                          f2.getName().replaceAll("^(?i)The ", ""));
}
```

Added a `(?i)` flag before the `regex pattern` to do a  *case insensitive*  replace (Thanks to @Chris for pointing this).

`Caret (^)` is added before the pattern, so that it replaces only the `The` at the beginning of the string. So, `The banana` will be replaced with `banana`, but `Banana, The` will not be replaced with `Banana,`. It will remain the same.

Comment: Beat me to it :) You'll probably want to do a case insensitive replace to catch 'the ' as well as 'The ' though

Comment: Just one case.If String dont start with "The" and it comes in between somewhere like Appthe (just example). `ReplaceAll` with regex will be a good idea I guess

Comment: @Ajinkya.. Nice catch. Taken care of that.

Comment: What behaviour would you like in case "The" is appended like in "Banana, The"? Maybe you would want to normalise your entries to that format before sorting. It all depends on the goal of your project.

Comment: @EricTobias.. Of course that depends upon all the possible filenames, and how to consider each of them while sorting, that OP has to tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return NaturalComparator.compareNatural(collator, f1.getName().startsWith("The  ")?f1.getName().substring(4) : f1.getName(), f2.getName().startsWith("The ")?f2.getName().substring(4):f2.getName();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static String ignoreThe(String s) {
    if (s.length > 3) {
        if (s.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase().equal("the ")) {
            return s.substring(0, 4);
        }
    }
    return s;
}

Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        String name1 = ignoreThe(f1.getName()); 
        String name1 = ignoreThe(f2.getName()); 
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
...
return NaturalComparator.compareNatural(collator, f1.getName().replaceAll("^The ", ""), f2.getName().replaceAll("^The ", ""));
```